# Apache Thrift serialization in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, thrift

I’m having a lot of trouble serializing data. What am I doing wrong?

```
std::string serialize(ContactsList& obj, std::string filename) {
    shared_ptr<TMemoryBuffer> transportOut(new TMemoryBuffer());
    shared_ptr<TBinaryProtocol> protocolOut(new TBinaryProtocol(transportOut));
    obj.write(protocolOut);
    std::string serialized_string = transportOut->getBufferAsString();
    return serialized_string;
}
```

This is the method I call from another method. I expect to get back a serialized binary string which I can write out to disk. Inside this serialize method, I create a TMemory buffer, then I wrap it in a TBinaryProtocol, and then the object’s write method, which will write itself into the memory buffer. Then, I get that buffer back as a string. I’d then write out the serialized string to disk.

I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘addressbook::ContactsList::write(boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport> >&)
```

As well as this note:

```
note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport> >’ to ‘apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*
```

I'm using Apache Thrift 1.0-dev, C++ 98 if these things make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

In c++ you can use the TFileTransport and a Thrift protocol of your choice, i.e. TBinaryProtocol:

```
shared_ptr<TFileTransport> transport(new TFileTransport(filename));
shared_ptr<TBinaryProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
yourObj.write(protocol.get()); // to write
```

or

```
yourObj.read(protocol.get()); // to read
```

to make sure the file exists you can use a open before:

```
open(filename.c_str(), O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY, 0666); // create file
```

ps.: It's actually very similar in all other target languages.

Answer (score 2):

The ThriftObject.write() function expects an argument of type

```
apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*
```

i.e. a 'Raw' pointer of type TProtocol. The protocolOut object used here is of shared pointer of the type.

```
shared_ptr<TBinaryProtocol> protocolOut
```

The 'get()' method of shared_ptr gives the raw pointer being managed by the shared_ptr object.
Hence using

```
obj.write(protocolOut.get());
```

should resolve the problem

Comment: Updated answer with details